# Is GeForce GTX 660 compatible with a Dell Inspiron 660?

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, compatibility

I am thinking about purchasing a GeForce GTX 660 graphics card for my Dell Inspiron 660 desktop computer, but I've never purchased a GFX card before, and I'm not sure if it is compatible with said computer.

This is my PC: http://www.bestbuy.com/site/dell-inspiron-3000-desktop-8gb-memory-1tb-hard-drive/4629248.p?id=1219100305398&skuId=4629248&ref=06&loc=01&ci_src=14110944&ci_sku=4629248&extensionType=pla:g&s_kwcid=PTC!pla!!!42057919639!g!!49989914959&kpid=4629248&k_clickid=1d979b0c-770e-8048-7a30-0000198a19d5

And this is the GFX card: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814130825

So all I want to know is if I can use that GFX card with my PC or not. Help would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless someone has the very same PC they can't answer the question exactly. There's a few things you need to look for

You absolutely need at least one PCIe X16 slot, and a 6 pin PCI power connector.

If you can find one of these slots

[image]

and

one of these power connectors

[image]

You're good

If your PSU is missing the connector, you can replace it, but without a x16 connector there's *no* way you can use the video card